# Firefox & IE: Corrupted data when retrieved from cache

Tags: asp.net, caching, http-headers, etag

I have a request to the server which looks like this:

```
http://localhost/Combine.aspx/flag/file1.js,file2.js,file3.js
```

I have also tried this:

```
http://localhost/Combine.aspx/flag/value/file1.js/file2.js/file3.js
```

It simply combines the three files which it was given: this works fine.

Upon the first request from Firefox, the page displays correctly. When the page is refreshed again, the content looks like this:

```
��������`I�%&/m�{J�J��t��`$�����iG#)�*��eVe]f@�흼��{���{��;�N'
```

In that case, *no* request is made to the server, the file is only retrieved from the firefox cache, as far as I can tell.

If I force-refresh the page with Control-F5, the page looks normal again.

Here is the request and response (in firebug) with **Control-F5** (works):

**Response**

```
Cache-Control   public
Content-Type    application/javascript; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding    gzip
Expires Sun, 26 Feb 2012 02:57:26 GMT
Last-Modified   Fri, 07 Jan 2011 21:08:54 GMT
Etag    CLYvZwbFmainWEMi8h-6x-zNEIQ1
Vary    Accept-Encoding
Server  Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Set-Cookie  auth=longstring; path=/
X-AspNet-Version    2.0.50727
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
Date    Thu, 03 Mar 2011 02:57:26 GMT
Content-Length  918
```

**Request**

```
Host    localhost
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.14) Gecko/20110218 Firefox/3.6.14
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/;q=0.8
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive  115
Connection  keep-alive
Cookie  auth=longstring
Pragma  no-cache
Cache-Control   no-cache
```

Here is the same with **just F5** (doesn't work):

**Response**:

```
Cache-Control   public
Content-Type    application/javascript; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding    gzip
Expires Sun, 26 Feb 2012 02:57:26 GMT
Last-Modified   Fri, 07 Jan 2011 21:08:54 GMT
Etag    CLYvZwbFmainWEMi8h-6x-zNEIQ1
Vary    Accept-Encoding
Server  Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version    2.0.50727
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
Date    Thu, 03 Mar 2011 03:01:31 GMT
Content-Length  1533
```

**Request**:

```
Host    localhost
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.14) Gecko/20110218 Firefox/3.6.14
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/;q=0.8
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive  115
Connection  keep-alive
Cookie  auth=longstring
```

The only thing that I can tell is different is the Content-Length (which is likely causing the corruption), but since it never hits the server, I have no control over it.

What could be causing this?

Edit:

This happens on IE8 as well, but instead of viewing a corrupt file, it downloads the corrupt file. No request is ever made to the server (set a breakpoint in visual studio).

As for chrome, when viewing the url directly, a request to the server is made every time, and it works every time. I believe, though, that if it were included in a  tag, it would behave similar to Firefox.

**Oh, and also:**

If I turn off the Expires header (which is one of the flags in the URL), *everything works fine*.

Edit 2:

I was able to work around this by not sending *both* an Expires and ETag header, only one or the other. I have no clue why an ETag header would cause such corruption, though.

Comment: That is very strange. Have you already tried clearing the cache from the setting of Firefox? Have you tried this on other browsers to see if you get the same error?

Comment: See the edit, it happens in IE8, but not chrome (when viewing the url directly).

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. I've looked and looked, but i can't find a reason for why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of your IIS configuration. Adjust IIS as  ASP 4.0 Classic, not Default Application Pool